# How strong is the promise that .so.x.y.z will exist?

Tags: libraries, linker

I have an application that requires OpenCV 2.4.11 to link, so in my `make` file I ensure I use the following linker flag pattern:

```
-l:libopencv_core.so.2.4.11
```

How robust is this assumption?

My specific problem is with my own machine, Ubuntu 14.04, which has v2.4.7 as default, so if I just use `-lopencv_core` I get the wrong version pulled in. I use `cv::fisheye` which is a 2.4.11 or later feature, and CMake's `find_package(OpenCV)` doesn't have a version specification feature.

Answer (score 2):

That makes it rely upon a specific package configuration (rather fragile).
It wouldn't run against an earlier or *later* version of the library.

If your application requires some specific feature (which cannot be immediately checked by success/failure in linking), the usual approach is to write some initialization code which checks for the release-version of the library (many, not all libraries have a version-function or global variable).

For instance, OpenCV (according to [How to determine OpenCV version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030640/how-to-determine-opencv-version)) has such a function:

```
printf("OpenCV: %s", cv::getBuildInformation().c_str());
```

Further reading: [OpenCV 2.4.10 documentation](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/mzucker1/opencv-2.4.10-docs/modules/core/doc/utility_and_system_functions_and_macros.html) for [getBuildInformation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#ga0ae377100bc03ce22322926bba7fdbb5):

> Returned value is raw cmake output including version control system revision, compiler version, compiler flags, enabled modules and third party libraries, etc. Output format depends on target architecture.

Comment: My specific problem is with my own machine, Ubuntu 14.04, which has v2.4.7 as default, so if I just use `-lopencv_core` I get the wrong version pulled in. I use `cv::fisheye` which is a 2.4.11 or later feature, and CMake's `find_package(OpenCV)` doesn't have a version specification feaure.

Comment: Regarding `CMake`, it's scriptable and you could revise its macros to do many things (outside the scope of this question).  A runtime check on the resulting executable is more straightforward.